# Finding relationship/correlation between two rasters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have two rasters: one with categorical values (vegetation types) and one with a continuous variable (lets say rainfall in mm), and I want to find the relationship.

From the start I thought it would be easy to do it simply in ArcMap or just export the data to Rstudio (or similar) to do statistical analysis for significance value etc.

I have not found a way yet, I  was only able to get the mean rainfall for each category using zonal statistics.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot perform a correlation between an nominal and continuous variable. I would consider a chi-square or t-test.

Comment: Mean rainfall per category is a perfectly fine characterization of a relationship.  Could you be more specific, then, about what kind of "relationship" you are looking for?